# PHP Drop down list with data from localhost not showing

Tags: php, mysql, database, localhost

Im currently working on a project and i have to show the inserted location into a dropdown. (inserting "Amsterdam" into locatie(table) in row Locatie)
After i've done that, i need to see "Amsterdam" in my Drop Down List

I've tried this:

```
<td>Locatie</td>
            <select name="locatie" id="per1">
            <option selected="selected">Choose one</option>
            <?php
            include_once("../config");

            $sql = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT Locatie FROM locatie");

            $rows = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
            foreach($rows as $row){

            echo "<option value='" . $row['locatie']. "'>" . $row['locatie'] . '</option>';
            }
            ?>
            </select>
```

Is there anyone that could help me? My Database name is toolsforeverdatabase (in localhost)

I'm new to php and stackoverflow so i'm really unexperience but would love to learn about it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: any error message? I may have some kind of blindness, but if the `config` code does connect to database then all looks good.

Comment: make sure your db isn't case-sensitive. `Locatie` and `locatie` could be two different animals depending on the OS. Use both php's error reporting and `mysqli_error($mysqli)` on the query.

Comment: Nope, no error giving but it's not showing my 'locatie' thats inside my database. And i assume that my database (connection) is correct because adding employee's is working (even adding with a dropdown thats inserted with HTML)

Answer (score 0):

```
  $sql = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT Locatie FROM locatie");
```

Please check in Config File whether the connection name is `$mysqli` or not.

if the Connection name is `$mysqli` use the below code

```
    <td>Locatie</td>
        <select name="locatie" id="per1">
        <option selected="selected">Choose one</option>
        <?php
        require '../config.php';

        $sql = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT Locatie FROM locatie");

        while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){

        echo '<option value='" . $rows['locatie']. "'>" . $rows['locatie'] . "</option>';
        }
        ?>
        </select>
```

Hope this will help ..

Comment: My config looks like this: 
<?php

$databaseHost = 'localhost';
$databaseName = 'toolsforeverdatabase';
$databaseUsername = 'root';
$databasePassword = '';
$mysqli = mysqli_connect($databaseHost, $databaseUsername, $databasePassword, $databaseName); 
 
?>

Comment: use `require '../config.php';`

Comment: It's now showing:    " . $row['locatie'] . "    (it's the second $row['locatie']

But still not the inserted data.. im so confused

Comment: `echo '<option value='" . $rows['locatie']. "'>" . $rows['locatie'] . "</option>';`

Comment: It's still only showing the $row['locatie'].

According to PHP Code Checker it's this error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting ',' or ';' in your code